# Dynamically setting visibility of textview in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view where the first item has to have a header. The way I've implemented it currently is to get the adapter position and if it is 0 then I set the textview containing the header to visible and set it to gone for any other value. 
However when I remove the first item via notifyItemRemoved, then the header isn't visible on the new first item (I.e what was previously the second item). Can someone please tell me what I need to do?

UPDATE: What I mean is that i have the header text in the view itself and I need to toggle the visibility depending on whether the view is the first one in the recyclerview.

So currently I toggle the visibility in the onBindViewHolder method where I check if the position is 0 and then set the heading visibility to View.VISIBLE else to VIEW.GONE. However in order for this to work any time I have any changes to the adapter then I need to recreate the whole adapter again and set it to the recycler view.

Apologies for not posting the code but it contains some sensitive information that I can't disclose

Comment: You should start by posting the relevant code.

Comment: At which point are you performing the first logic. If it is in the adapter then what is happening is that, the logic has already been executed and will not take effect after you notifyItemRemoved. Probably remove the item from the list and set the recycler view list again

Answer (score 1):

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {



    if(position==5) {
       holder.textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `getItemViewType(int position)` method to decide at what position what item should be.

```
private static final int HEADER = 0;
private static final int ITEMS = 1;
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    if (position == 0) {
        return HEADER;
    } else {
        return ITEMS;
    }
}
```

in `getItemCount()` you have to add one more item because we have header

```
 @Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return sections.size() + 1;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. However the header isn't a separate view but just a textview that should automatically become visible when the view is the in the first position

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the answers.
However, they haven't solved my issue and at least for now I've solved it by using the layout manager of the recyclerview to get the view position and if the position of the view to be removed is 0 then I set the header textview to visible of the second view and call notifyItemRemoved. If the position is not 0 then I just call notifyItemRemoved.